# Using Facebook Community Help Center as a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is it possible to use Facebook Community Help Center as a Page? I cannot tell whether it works without writing an answer or a question (which I am trying to prevent as to not get notifications to my personal profile)

Comment: I couldn't even visit the help center as a Page. Got HTTP 500 error. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If you are using Facebook as your page, posts in the Help Center will still be made under your personal profile.  These posts do not appear on the Timeline or in the News Feed.  You will be subscribed to the question, which means that you'll get notifications on new answers, but you can click "Unfollow" on the question page to stop those (you may need to refresh the question for this option to appear if you have just  posted).